# How do I make pads for "spades" on my PCB in Eagle?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I've seen many devices with spade-like connectors (DC Jacks, AV connectors, etc.) such as below:

[image]

The datasheet for the above connector has the follow pad layout:

[image]

However, there is no drill hole / line cutout on the pads. Is there a way in Eagle to specify a line cutout rather than a drill hole so the board house knows what to do?

Making drill holes makes it very hard for the solder to adhere onto the connector, because there are huge semi-circle gaps around the flat connector.

Comment: fyi: Plated slots usually cost extra when it comes to PCB fabrication.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Is there such thing called non-plated slots?

Comment: Yes, there are such things as non-plated slots (and non-plated holes too).  They usually serve mechanical purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to make slots.
Just make a hole with a diameter as the size of the slot and it will work. You could always look for the same SMT varient...

Comment: This really isn't an answer to my question.. What you're saying is what I currently do. However, as stated, there are large semicircle areas around the connection. This makes it 1. Hard to solder. 2. Mechanical strength is very poor.

Comment: You can make slots and the fab will make them but it will cost much more than holes as the board will have to go through CNC process and not just drilling. I don't quite understand why is this harder to solder with holes and why the mechanical strength is poor? Did you have parts come out by pulling them?